# RequireJS self reference inside jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scope, requirejs

I am using RequireJS with jQuery. I have a module `page` that includes a function that toggles the visibility of a menu on the site. I call that toggle function by calling `page.toggleMenu` outside the module or `this.toggleMenu` inside the module.

The problem/question I have is whether or not I can access that module inside a jQuery function called from within that same module, like this:

```
var someFunction = function() {
    $('.someelement').on('click',function() {
        this.toggleMenu();
    });
}
```

So far I have been unable to do this. The `this` variable it turns out contains the DOM element for .someelement. I am guessing that this is because the scope of jQuery is only the DOM. But I am not sure what is going on here. I'm also surprised that the `this` variable is a reference to the DOM element. I thought the only way to achieve this was by doing `var this = $(this)`.

It would be very helpful if someone could help clarify for me what is going on here, and what (if any) options I have for a potential workaround. Finally, is this the reason that one might use MooTools instead of jQuery?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? So we have some idea how your `page` module is set up? Right now we have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your module (or whatever scope it is where you're using `this.someFunction`), put:

```
var page = this;
```

...and then use `page.someFunction` rather than `this.someFunction`.